# cannot convert argument 1 from const wchar_t[9] to wchar_t

Tags: c++

**[FULL CODE](https://github.com/SimonStrands/directx2D/tree/master)**

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKZvT4U71rg&index=8&list=PLKK11Ligqitij8r6hd6tfqqesh3T_xWJA) and have followed step by step from his tutorial and when he came to episode 8 I got an error in Level1.h.

```
void Level1::Load()
    {
        sprites = new SpriteSheet(L"test.png", gfx);
    }
```

> **ERROR**
>
> 'SpriteSheet::SpriteSheet(const SpriteSheet &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const wchar_t [9]' to 'wchar_t *'

I have written both Level1.h, Spritesheet.cpp and Spritesheet.h more than twice, tried to take away the "L" before the "test.png".
Also want to point out that I have Visual Studio 2017.

I would love you if you can solve my problem <3.

[Full code](https://github.com/SimonStrands/directx2D/tree/master)

Comment: Sounds like your `SpriteSheet` constructor requires a `wchar_t*` parameter instead of `const wchar_t*`.  It's very unlikely that this needs to be non-const, since constructors should not modify their arguments.

Comment: Please don't link to off-site content, as the links may go stale or your code may be updated and not reflect your issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literal strings in C++ are really constant arrays of the character type, that's why `L"test.png"` is mentioned as the type`const wchar_t [9]` (the size is `9` to fit the terminator).

As any other array it can decay to a pointer to its first element, and this pointer have the type `const wchar_t*`.

Note the use of `const` in the types above... That's what's missing in your constructor argument. It needs to be

```
SpriteSheet(const wchar_t* filename, Graphics*gfx);
//          ^^^^^
// Note the const here
```